# Simulating Multiple key-presses with .trigger();

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Currently I am making a script that when injected into Google Chrome console, it will gather some information and form it in a string, take that string and convert the text to each characters respective char code.

My issue lies in trying to get jQuery to simulate a key press on an input field, and input the charcodes into that field.

Take a look at my code:

```
var text = $('[id^="nhwMiddlegwt-uid"]').html();
var text_middle = $('[id^="nhwMiddleCommagwt-uid"]').html();
var text_after = $('[id^="nhwRightgwt-uid"]').html();
var finished = text + text_middle + text_after;

console.log(finished);
var output, output_format = "";
for(i=0; i<finished.length; i++) {
    if(output != "") output += ", ";
    output += finished.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

The output variable contains text like this, "87, 101, 98, 32, 68, 101, 118, 101, 108, 111, 112, 109, 101, 110, 116" which is the char code characters for, "Web Development".

Now I need to take the char code string "output" and change the value of an input field.

I have tried using this something similar to this:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 84; // # Some key code value
$(".txtInput").val(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
$(".txtInput").trigger(e);
```

Now this works if you're only trying to trigger the keypress simulation for one key, 84, but will not work for my whole output variable. I've tried looping through in a for loop, but the .trigger() event won't allow me to do that because the .which command that is added to the end of a variable is not allowed in a for loop, look below:

```
for(i=0; i<finished.length; i++) {
        if(output != "") output += ", ";
        output.which += finished.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

So, how can I get .trigger(); to loop through every char code in the option variable?

Edit: Just to clarify, I do NOT want to just change the input value. I want to simulate a keypress on an input field, using the "output" variable char codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var arr = [
    87
    , 101
    , 98
    , 32
    , 68
    , 101
    , 118
    , 101
    , 108
    , 111
    , 112
    , 109
    , 101
    , 110
    , 116
    ];

var output = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, arr);

$("#txtInput")
.on("keydown.str", function(e) {
  alert(e.target.value)
})
.prop("value", output)
.trigger("keydown.str");
```

```js
var arr = [
    87
    , 101
    , 98
    , 32
    , 68
    , 101
    , 118
    , 101
    , 108
    , 111
    , 112
    , 109
    , 101
    , 110
    , 116
    ];

var output = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, arr);

$("#txtInput")
.on("keydown.str", function(e) {
  alert(e.target.value)
})
.prop("value", output)
.trigger("keydown.str");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtInput" type="text" />
```

Comment: For your code it's giving me the error "TypeError: undefined is not a function". Just so you know, the first item in my array is for some reason being set as undefined, but every other character after that is the correct char code.

Comment: @mathewblair Not displayin `alert()` at stacksnippets ? Try updated post. Provided a `this` (`String`) for `.apply()`